# Retrieving a record from a stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I am very new to ASP.NET so I apologize for the naive question but I was just wondering how do I retrieve the data from a stored procedure I am calling from within ASP.NET .The stored procedure is supposed to return a single row and I want to retrieve the record fields  returned.

So this is what I have come up with so far

**The stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure6

@LoginName varchar(50)

AS
 SELECT username ,Password  FROM dbo.Users
 Where username = @LoginName
RETURN
```

The code to get access to the specific record within the asp.net.cs file

```
var user = dbcontext.returnuserdetails(txtEmailAddress.Text);
```

where returnuserdetails is the function I added via the model browser in Visual studio 2010

Now the question is how do I get and store the values of the username and password which are returned ?

I am working in ASP.NET 4.0 if it helps.

Thanks

Comment: What are going to do with the user's information? Do you just want a way of identifying who the user is after they are logged in? If so, you could place user.username in to the Session.

Comment: @Andrew Charlton Well The objective currently is just to check if the username being entered in the form fields is unique (I plan to match it with the data retrieved and if there is an match ,throw an error stating that the user name is unique) .But in the longer run I plan to use the password for authentication purposes.

This might not be the most efficient way to do it but I am still finding my way around

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL? You mention the model browser. If you just want to check if a username exists, create a function that explicitly accomplishes this with a count of Users with the entered username. If the result is greater than 0 then throw the error. Authentication can be handled separately and more securely.

Comment: Well I am using the entity framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are in 4.0 you can easily just use the LINQ to SQL stuff, no need for stored procedure here.

```
private void GetUser(string emailAddress){

  using(DataContext dbcontext = new DataContext()){
    var AppData.user = dbcontext.users
             .Select(u => u.email_address == emailAddress).SingleOrDefault();

    // access entity properties as needed
    // user.email_address, user.first_name, etc..

  }    

}
```

That said you aren't really stating what it is you are trying to do with the user entity and passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored as plain text.

if you are forced to use Stored Procedures then the return in LINQ-to-SQL will always be a set.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ReturnUserDetails

@LoginName varchar(50)

AS
 SELECT * -- Get whole row so you have all info that is possibly needed  
 FROM dbo.Users
 Where username = @LoginName
RETURN
```

C# Code

```
private void GetUser(string userName){

      using(DataContext dbcontext = new DataContext()){
        var user = dbcontext.ReturnUserDetails(userName).SingleOrDefault();

        // access entity properties as needed
        string userName =  user.username;
        var password = user.Password;

      }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,the issue is that the DBA wants everyone accessed as stored procedures so I am going that route.

That said,the passwords are encrypted using SHA1 encryption before they are stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

Use [SqlDataReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

Edit:
This is a code sample from the link, now the difference between this sample and your case is that you should specify you command type as StoredProcedure.
If it still doesn't help let me know.

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @@AtoMerZ ,can you please elaborate .I went through the link you suggested but I am still confused.